# PHP Laravel - Nested blade loop requiring SQL query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to return a loop to my blade template file with below result:

- **Main Name**

  - Sub name #1
  - Sub name #2
- **Main Name**

  - Sub name #1
  - Sub name #2

etc..

I have created a controller for this:

`MergerController.php`

```
public function index()
{

    $MainOrganisations = DB::table('test')
    ->select('address', 'code', DB::raw('count(*) as amount'))  
    ->where('code', 'LIKE', '64%')
    ->groupBy('address')
    ->orderBy('amount', 'desc')
    ->get();

    foreach($MainOrganisations as $value){

        $SubOrganisations = DB::table('test')
        ->select('name', 'code')
        ->where('address', $value->address)
        ->where('code', 'NOT LIKE', '64%')
        ->get();
    }

    $data = [
        'MainOrganisations'     => $MainOrganisations,
        'SubOrganisations'      => $SubOrganisations,
    ];

    #Return data to our view
    return view('merger.list')->with($data);
}
```

Then, inside my view file, I try to show this data:

`list.blade.php`

```
   <table>
    @foreach ($MainOrganisations as $Main)
        <thead>
            <th colspan="2">{{ $Main->address }}</th>
        </thead>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Code</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($SubOrganisations as $Sub)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $Sub->name }}</td>       
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>

    @endforeach
    </table>
```

However, above only return the **first** result from `$SubOrganisations`, and then loops ONLY that result in my nested foreach:

```
@foreach($SubOrganisations as $Sub)
      <tr>
         <td>{{ $Sub->name }}</td>      
      </tr>
@endforeach
```

Returns:

- Sub name #1
- Sub name #1
- Sub name #1

Comment: `$SubOrganisations = DB::table('test')...` you keep resetting this variable every iteration, so it will only be the result from the last iteration

Comment: @lagbox How can I do so it's not resetting it? Adding it to an array?

Comment: You should add the SubOrganisation as a child of MainOrganisations instead of having in the same level.

Comment: Should I add `SubOrganisation` as a child in my controller? Apologize if these are simple questions, I am still quite new to this, so just trying to get a better understanding. A simple example would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are looping through each data for sub organization is wrong. Its better yo use eloquent relationship with eager loading for better performance.

Change your controller code:

```
public function index()
{

    $MainOrganisations = DB::table('test')
    ->select('address', 'code', DB::raw('count(*) as amount'))  
    ->where('code', 'LIKE', '64%')
    ->groupBy('address')
    ->orderBy('amount', 'desc')
    ->get();

    foreach($MainOrganisations as $key => $MainOrganisation){

        $SubOrganisations = DB::table('test')
        ->select('name', 'code')
        ->where('address', $MainOrganisation->address)
        ->where('code', 'NOT LIKE', '64%')
        ->get();

        $MainOrganisation->subOrganisations = $SubOrganisations;
    }

    $data = [
        'MainOrganisations'     => $MainOrganisations
    ];

    #Return data to our view
    return view('merger.list')->with($data);
}
```

In you view:

```
<table>
    @foreach ($MainOrganisations as $Main)
        <thead>
            <th colspan="2">{{ $Main->address }}</th>
        </thead>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Code</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($Main->subOrganisations as $Sub)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $Sub->name }}</td>       
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>

    @endforeach
    </table>
```

Comment: This gives me "double arrow" error on `=> $SubOrganisations;`. `$value` is not defined anywhere. And error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Please check the edited answer, there was a type error

Comment: Still cannot use `$value`

Comment: This gives me error `cannot use object of type stdClass as array php laravel` at this line: `$MainOrganisations[$key]['subOrganisations'] = $SubOrganisations;`